# Microservice Architecture- cross-domain chattiness

Tags: architecture, soa, microservices

I have a relatively new project that employs a microservice architecture. I feel pretty good about the size and granularity of the individual services, with the exception or our security service.

I have three main services, let's say `foo-service`, `bar-service`, and `baz-service`. These services never need to communicate, but all three services regularly talk via HTTP requests to the `security-service`. I want this to stop for a variety of reasons- the biggest is that each request to my individual services spawns a request to the security service, which can turn into several extra hops once you account for load balancing, etc. I've been reading "Software Architecture Patterns" by Mark Richards, and he recommends in these instances you should share databases and violate DRY: copy the required functionality into each service. Still, he uses this example with smaller "utility" classes, which may not really apply in this instance.

The security service isn't that big, so I could definitely copy it into each of the other services. That said, it's just big enough that I don't feel great copying and pasting it - 314 'relevant' lines of code according to coveralls (java so there's a lot more actual code ;-). I could easily turn it into a module that each service brings in- but then my services have a shared dependency and that has bit me in the past. Of course the security code will grow over time as we add authentication methods, but we aren't reinventing the wheel when it comes to auth so It's mostly integrating with other libraries and authentication services. That is, I don't imagine this particular code base getting huge.

So my question, should I copy and paste the code or build a module that every service brings in? Thanks!

Comment: This feels like a cross-cutting concern that Siteminder was born for.  It should be a filter or basic auth on the services, not extra network hops.

Comment: We are filtering the service requests. Just using basic for now (this is new), but have requirements to use specific oauth providers later. The primary thing the security service is actually doing now is managing authorization via security groups. That's really the functionality that I think I'll need to move into each service (so everyone isn't checking in with security service for authorization)

Comment: what specifically does the security service do, authentication or authorization?

Comment: The security service main responsibility is creating/maintaining security groups, which every other service leverages for determining access to specific resources.

Comment: maybe using http cache (between your services and the security service) is the solution (it depends on your security policy (eg. if credentials change, if so, then if it's possible to leave some buffer to propagate, etc.) and traffic characteristic)

Comment: Is the main concern performance related?

Answer (score 4):

> I want this to stop for a variety of reasons- the biggest is that each request to my individual services spawns a request to the security service, which can turn into several extra hops once you account for load balancing, etc.

PROS of leaving as a separate service:
 -  Changes to security business logic only affect the security service and do not need a change to the client services.

PROS of moving security logic into client services:
-  Speed/performance.
-  One less service to manage might mean reduced operation costs.

Speed (performance) might trump here, depending on what the requirements are, but it will come with increased development costs.

If you do move the security logic into its own re-usable module that can be called from within the other services just do a good job at encapsulating it and following basic lose-coupling-tight-cohesion design.  Also, since you might have to defend this decision for years to come, please have a good explanation so your future boss does not fire you when she asks why does it cost so much to update our security logic.  Have benchmarks readily available, people lie, numbers don't.  I once had a one page benchmark results for a new DB I begged for.  I was asked multiple times from different people as to why I went with the new DB... I would just send them the one page and never heard any further questions from that person.

This video might make you feel better with regard sto bucking the trend:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StCrm572aEs

It shows how and why Netflix bucked the trend and did not go with REST architecture for their API's.  Basically architecture is a customer of requirements and cost, its not the other way around.

EDIT:  Another big PRO for leaving as a service is that you might have to create multiple modules for each language being supported.  At my job our security services are used by client services across multiple languages.

Comment: One thing that has been rattling around in my head since I asked this question, if I make this change for speed, am I prematurely optimizing? This stuff is greenfield and is currently very performant, might I be wasting a bunch of time when some other aspect of the system that I'm not even aware of is going to be the actual performance killer?

Comment: Yes it can be seen as premature optimization.  Yes you might be wasting time.  There is a good saying that comes to mind "no good deed goes unpunished".

Answer (score 1):

If you embed the security logic into the other services, then you really can't call it a microservice architecture now can you? I also understand that having that extra and duplicitous server round trip for every other service can be a bit of a drag. Here are some viable alternatives for you to consider.

Put all four of these microservices behind a firewall. Expose a public facing service that uses the security service to validate the incoming request and then call the other services if the request is valid for the given credentials. The other services always trust the caller which is a service owned and operated within your trusted environment.

If this is a "fire-and-forget" use case and you feel uncomfortable about that public facing service having too much orchestration responsibilities, then consider this alternative. The public facing service sends the inbound request to an unauthorized queue in a message broker. The security service consumes from that queue and performs the authentication. If valid, then the security service queues the message up on an authorized queue. Any number of microservices after that consume from the authorized queue and perform their respective operation.

Answer (score 0):

Security as a separate service that you need for every request as you describe it is an extremely bad idea. May I refer you to the basic ideas of modularisation that Parnas described so eloquently in [On the Criteria To Be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf) . No coupling also means no cohesion, and  engineering is about finding the sweet spot on that axis.

Contrary to popular belief, micro-services need to be rather large to be able to scale. The limits to scalability are mostly in communications, so they need to be designed to not be chatty. The problem is mostly (unless you're netflix) not bandwidth but delay.

Your security module needs to be closer to your services than a HTTP request, a linked-in module can be fine.